# Most efficient way of having separate delivery and billing addresses on an Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an `Address` model and an `Order` model in my Rails app. An order has a billing address and a delivery address. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way of implementing this with a polymorphic association (other models will also have addresses in future) and this is the code I've come up with:

**address.rb:**

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :line_1, :line_2, :city, :county, :postcode
  # Also has an 'address_type' attribute

  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**order.rb:**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable

  def delivery_address
    addresses.where(address_type: 'delivery').first
  end

  def delivery_address=(address)
    address.address_type = 'delivery'
    addresses << address
  end

  def billing_address
    addresses.where(address_type: 'billing').first
  end

  def billing_address=(address)
    address.address_type = 'billing'
    addresses << address
  end
end
```

**Adding an address:**

```
Order.first.address = Address.new(line_1: 'My House', city: 'Cityville, county: 'Hazzard')
```

This almost works except that trying to change an address by calling `order.delivery_address=` again just adds another address of type 'delivery'. I'm also pretty sure that there must be a more elegant way of doing it and I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: I think you have this backwards. Address should have many orders, and orders should belong to 2 different addresses. And all those methods should be handled by those 2 associations directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_one :delivery_address, as: :addressable,
         conditions: "addresses.address_type = 'delivery'", class_name: "Address"
has_one :billing_address,  as: :addressable,
         conditions: "addresses.address_type = 'billing'", class_name: "Address"
```

Comment: i would drop the address type completely.

Answer (score -1):

The code looks great.  I think the difference between adding and changing an address should be handled in your controller, not the model, e.g. in a RESTful case, there are method for `create` and `update`, in which case you can know whether to replace the value or add it.

Also look at [Rails' support for Dirty attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html), which let you know if something has been changed.